# Cochin and common ligatures with font spec

Tags: xetex, fontspec, ligatures

I'm using Cochin as main font in a XeLaTeX project, and having Cochin glyphs for common ligatures such a `fi` and `fl`, I would expect those ligatures to be used by the `fontspec` package—but that's not happening.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}

\fontspec[Ligatures=TeX]{Cochin}

Testing common ligatures: ``fi'' or ``fl''.

Explicitly pasted glyphs: ``ﬁ'' (\texttt{U+FB01}) and ``ﬂ'' (\texttt{U+FB02}).

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Cochin is a commercial font, and cannot be tested.

Comment: It should be the same as `Ligatures=TeX`, but does using `Mapping=tex-text` instead have any effect? I don't own the font and cannot test.

Comment: The question is whether they are set up correctly in the font. If the tables are correctly configured, it should work. If not, I don't know if there's a way of working around it. Use of system fonts is beholden to the quality of the fonts installed in a way that use of traditional TeX fonts is not. (The latter are beholden instead to the quality of the support package installed or created.)

Comment: @Bernard - A minor detail, in the grand design of things: `Cochin` is a system font on MacOSX computer systems.

Comment: Not an answer, just an observation: The issue you're encountering also occurs if the MWE is compiled with LuaLaTeX instead of XeLaTeX. :-(

Comment: If you’re looking for a Cochin in which the ligatures work, I can say that ligatures do work in Linotype’s Cochin LT Pro.

Comment: @Thérèse where can I find Cochin LT Pro? Is it included into a graphic software suite like Adobe CS?

Comment: @Heruan I don’t know what’s included in Adobe’s software suites: Adobe stopped supporting GNU/Linux some years ago, and I’ve returned the favor.  But you can get Cochin LT Pro from https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/cochin/ (be sure to select the Pro fonts, not the standard ones).  If you’re interested in Nicolas Cochin beyond this particular typeface, LTC Nicolas Cochin (https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/lanston/ltc-nicolas-cochin/) is very well executed.